# Why is Angular displaying raw HTML?

Tags: javascript, angular

I just started learning Angular and my HTML does not interpolate the values I set it. It just displays the raw HTML. Here is my HTML page

```
<p>to-do-items works!</p>
<h2>{{toDoItems.name}} Details</h2>
<div><span>id: </span>{{toDoItems.id}}</div>
<div><span>name:</span>{{toDoItems.name}}</div>
<div><span>is complete: </span>{{toDoItems.isComplete}}</div>
```

This is my typescript for the component

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ToDoItem} from "../to-do-item";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-to-do-items',
  templateUrl: './to-do-items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./to-do-items.component.css']
})
export class ToDoItemsComponent implements  OnInit{
toDoItems: ToDoItem = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Danny",
  isComplete: false
}

constructor(){}
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

and this is my typescript to declare all the variables

```
 export class ToDoItem{
      constructor(
      public id: number,
      public name: string,
      public isComplete: boolean
    ){}

}
```

Comment: ngOnInit() should not be part of the constructor, so i think this dont compile because the interface OnInit is not implemented

Comment: Are there errors in the console?

Comment: how do I implement OnInit? and no errors in the console

Comment: ngOnInit is right. The indentation makes it look like it's inside the constructor, but the constructor closes before the ngOnInit. The last `}` is the closing bracket of the class.

Comment: It now works, apparently I just retyped in ng serve to restart the server within my terminal and clicked on the local host link and it all worked.

Comment: Now I understand what I was doing wrong. I was clicking on the deploy in google chrome directly from the web storm/visual studio code application. You need to navigate to projects directory using "cd" and run the command "ng serve" from the terminal and navigate via hyperlink that it presents you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the error is in the structure of the interface for the `ToDoItem`

Component HTML

```
<p>to-do-items works!</p>
<h2>{{toDoItems.name}} Details</h2>
<div><span>id: </span>{{toDoItems.id}}</div>
<div><span>name:</span>{{toDoItems.name}}</div>
<div><span>is complete: </span>{{toDoItems.isComplete}}</div>
```

Component TS

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ToDoItem} from "../to-do-item";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-to-do-items',
  templateUrl: './to-do-items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./to-do-items.component.css']
})
export class ToDoItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  toDoItems: ToDoItem = {
    id: 1,
    name: "Danny",
    isComplete: false
  }

  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Interface TS (`interface` as opposed to `class` without `constructor()`)

```
export interface ToDoItem {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  isComplete: boolean;
}
```

Read more about interfaces here https://angular.io/tutorial/first-app/first-app-lesson-04

Comment: that doesnt work. I need the costructor() to initialize the members for further use.

Comment: Oh I see @Larrythelobster . Lemme make an update. It shouldn't be a class. It should just be an interface. I think that should do it. It has a slightly different syntax with `;` and not `,`.

Comment: I made all the suggested changes and have no idea why but it still does not work and just shows the literal raw HTML with no interpolation of values.

Comment: It now works, apparently I just retyped in ng serve to restart the server within my terminal and clicked on the local host link and it all worked.

Comment: Noice! I'm glad it worked @Larrythelobster ! I guess it just had to rebuild the assets for the changes to kick in properly or something. So you are using `interface` instead of `class`?